# Como evitar que el metodo createElement se replique después de utilizar el evento mouseover en Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript

**Tengo el siguiente código**

// Cuando coloco el mouse encima se crean 2 botones con el metodo createElement

```
let article = document.querySelector('.article')
article.addEventListener('mouseover', showButtons)


function showButtons (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let containerButtons = document.querySelector('.buttons')
    containerButtons.style.display = ''

    let createButtons = document.createElement('a')
    createButtons.innerHTML = 'More info'
    containerButtons.appendChild(createButtons)
    createButtons.classList.add('buttons__info')

    createButtons = document.createElement('a')
    createButtons.innerHTML = 'Buy'
    containerButtons.appendChild(createButtons)
    createButtons.classList.add('buttons__info')

   removeEventListener('mouseover', showButtons)

}


// Cuando quito el mouse desaparecen los 2 botones creados con el metodo createElement

article = document.querySelector('.wrapper')
article.addEventListener('mouseleave', hideButtons)

function hideButtons(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    containerButton = document.querySelector('.buttons')
    containerButton.style.display = 'none'

    removeEventListener('mouseleave', hideButtons)
}
```

El problema ocurre cuando vuelvo a posicionar el mouse encima ya que me replica nuevamente los botones y va generando sumando mas botones a los que ya hay.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considero que @RimuruTempest contesta tu pregunta.

En el caso en el cual necesitas crear los botones en javascript lo que tienes que hacer es crear una variable `let noHayBotones = true;`. Esto te dice que todavía no los has creado. Después de crearlos `noHayBotones = false;` Crearás los botones solo si no hay botones, o sea `noHayBotones = true;`

```js
let article = document.querySelector(".article");
let containerButtons = document.querySelector(".buttons");

let noHayBotones = true;


article.addEventListener("mouseover", showButtons);

function showButtons(e) {
  containerButtons.style.display = "block";
  if (noHayBotones) {
    //crea los dos botones solo si no los has creado 
    createButton("More info")
    createButton("Buy")
    //como que ya has creado los dos botones:
    noHayBotones = false;
  }
}

// Cuando quito el mouse desaparecen los 2 botones creados con el metodo createElement

article.addEventListener("mouseleave", hideButtons);

function hideButtons(e) {
  containerButtons = document.querySelector(".buttons");
  containerButtons.style.display = "none";
}


function createButton(elHTML){
    let nuevoBoton = document.createElement("a");
    nuevoBoton.innerHTML = elHTML;
    containerButtons.appendChild(nuevoBoton);
    nuevoBoton.classList.add("buttons__info");
}
```

```css
.article {
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
}
p {
  margin: 0.5em;
}

a {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border: solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<article class="article">
  <p>Hover me</p>
  <div class="buttons"></div>
</article>
```

También he creado una función `createButton` para no repetir tanto el código

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en que creas el elemento justo al hacer hover, y no deberías hacerlo de eso modo por que por eso mismo se te duplica.

Lo mas recomendable es crear el elemento en primer plano, además de que lo que estas tratando de hacer se puede hacer solo con css no necesariamente necesitas javascript.

De este modo

```css
.buttons {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
.buttons__info span {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 7px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  background-color: #345;
  color: #fff;
}
.buttons:hover > .buttons__info span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  Hover me
  <a class="buttons__info">
    <span>More info</span>
  </a>
  <a class="buttons__info">
    <span>Buy</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Si yo se que se puede hacer lo mismo con CSS, solo  quiero hacerlo directamente con Vanilla JavaScript como proceso de aprendizaje.